# Difference in area calculation and pixel count

Tags: r, pixel, area, qgis

I have a raster layer masked by river network in binary form. While calculating the no. of pixel in R (freq(raster)) and QGIS using r.report I found the same number in both. But in calculation of area in sq. km I found difference in area R calculated by (tapply(area(raster), raster[], sum)) and QGIS. However, the major problem that I have with this is why are the area calculation not in par with the pixel number? The resolution of the raster is 30sec (approx. 1km*1km) so the number of pixel has to be approx equal to the area in sq km. The raster has a geographic coordinate system OGC:CRS84 - WGS 84 (CRS84) - Geographic and is in .grd form. I also projected it to UTM for QGIS which slightly increased the area but not considerable difference.
I am also posting the reports from R and QGIS below and the please follow the link below if you want to have a look at the raster too. I want the value in areas so I really don't know if I should convert pixel number into area in sq km. which in this case should be equal or use one of the answers from R or QGIS.

In r.report in QGIS area in sq. km Vs pixel: 
0 value: 222, 520 Vs 290,767
1 value: 81,653 Vs 106,934

In Rstudio area in sq. km Vs pixel:
0 value: 222,068.53 Vs 290,767 
1 value: 81,484.18 Vs 106,934

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1pBba0ejIc4t9ayKl36nyIo3vbgD4BKCT?usp=sharing

Comment: area of grid cells is not a constant in geographic coordinate system (mainly because length of a degree of longitude varies with latitude). So there's no reason that area needs to be proportional to number of grid cells.  NB also, reprojecting to UTM will have changed the values calculated in QGIS

Comment: @dww so which answer should I follow R or QGIS? Also reprojecting would produce an error information?

Answer (score 1):

With the R `raster` package area is computed in m2 for longitude/latitude raster cells. Also note that at the equator, a 30 sec cell is about 860 m2, and this area decreases going towards to poles.

Given a the number of cells `n`, and the average latitude of you raster `lat`, the area should be about

```
n * 860 * cos(lat*pi/180)
```

An example to show the proper (memory-safe) way to do this in `raster`

```
#example data
library(raster)
r <- raster()
set.seed(67)
values(r) <- 0
r[sample(ncell(r), 1000)] <- 1

#select the cells that are not 0
rr <- reclassify(r, cbind(0,NA))

a <- area(rr)
aa <- mask(a, rr)

cellStats(aa, "sum")
```

---- with your data that is

```
r <- raster("raster.grd")
rr <- reclassify(r, cbind(0, NA))
a <- area(r)
aa <- mask(a, rr)
cellStats(aa, "sum")
#81484.18
```

That is, about 81 thousand km2

Comment: With the command that you have given I got the final answer [1] 508358771. Is this the area of non-zero value in sq. m? Does it not seem way off-base with the number of pixel being 106,934? In any case converting pixel no. directly to area would be wrong as you have said near the equator a 30 sec cell is about 860 m2. The area of interest is the Ganges-Brahmaputra-Meghna (GBM) + a little more area of another basin (raster link given in drive). Also in QGIS, I have used a grass gis plugin r.report, presents report in different metrics <https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/r.report.html>

Comment: It is the area of the cells that are not `NA`  --- see my expanded answer; I forgot to add the mask step

Comment: So with this new command I got the area 8031377. What is the unit of this area if its sq km it seems too large (8 million km2) and if its sq. m it seems too small (=8.03 km2). The pixel number calculated is 106,934 (non-zero value). Also why the generation of random number through set.seed?

Comment: I know include an example with your data. If you get another result with R, than show exactly how you get that in your question.

Comment: With your new code in "---- with your data that is" I did get (81484.18) but previously the code was a <- area(rr) as opposed to area(r) now which caused the error. I get the same answer with this too: (tapply(area(raster), raster[], sum)). Can this new command be used to calculate area anywhere in the globe? With the r.report in QGIS (a grass gis command) I get a slight difference (81,653). Would it be alright if I follow any one of these answers? Also thank you for the answers so far.